# URI formats are not supported Error streamreader

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, url

I'm trying to parse an XML from URL my code is

```
public List<docs> parsexml(string url, string siteType)
    {
        var docsList = new List<docs>();
        using (var xmlReader = new StreamReader(url))
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
            XNamespace nameSpace = "/response/result/";
            var xmlProducts = doc.Descendants(nameSpace + "docs");
```

I don't know what to use beside stream reader.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't you mean to load from the xmlReader?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes

Comment: Then it should be `XDocument.Load(xmlReader)` instead of `XDocument.Load(url)`, no?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks but my problem is streamreader it does'nt support url! i need to find a replace for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) with minimal code changes;

```
public List<docs> parsexml(string url, string siteType)
{
    var docsList = new List<docs>();

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead (url)) 
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
        XNamespace nameSpace = "/response/result/";
        var xmlProducts = doc.Descendants(nameSpace + "docs");
...
```

...or, maybe better, you could simplify it by just passing the URL to XDocument.Load();

```
public List<docs> parsexml(string url, string siteType)
{
    var docsList = new List<docs>();

    var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
    XNamespace nameSpace = "/response/result/";
    var xmlProducts = doc.Descendants(nameSpace + "docs");

...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("file:///c:/Test/file.xml");

WebResponse response = WebRequest.Create(uri).GetResponse();
using(Stream s = response.GetResponseStream()) {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s)) {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
        .........
    }
}
```